# set pagination on button click

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I need some help regarding pagination, the problem is that I want to show my database records first time on button click with pagination but every time I click on pagination link it requires click on button
Here is my code I know I am making some mistake please check and kindly do me a favor by correcting my mistake ..

```
if (isset($_POST["search"])){        
$result=mysql_query("select count(*) from reg_phone");
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
$tr=$row[0];
$rpp=4;
$pn=1;
if(isset($_GET['pn']))
{
$pn=$_GET['pn'];
}
$tp=($tr/$rpp);
if($tr/$rpp>=0)
{
    $tp++;
}
$from=(($pn-1)*$rpp)+1;
$to=($pn)*($rpp);       
$show = "SELECT * FROM reg_phone where Id between $from and $to";
$rs = mysql_query($show) or die(mysql_error());
#****results in Grid****
echo "<table width='100%' border='1' cellpadding='2' border-color='#000' id='tbl'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td style='background: white;'><b>IMEI #</td>";
echo "<td style='background: white;'><b>Phone #</td>";
echo "<td style='background: white;'><b>From Date</td>";
echo "<td style='background: white;'><b>Status</td>";
echo "</tr>";
$rowID = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td id='imeinum" . $rowID . "'>$row[imei]</td>";
echo "<td id='phnum" . $rowID . "'>$row[phonenum]</td>";
echo "<td id='datepicker" . $rowID . "'>$row[fdate]</td>";
echo "<td id='rad" . $rowID . "'>$row[status]</td>";
echo "</tr>";
            $rowID++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<ul id='pages'>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$tp;$i++)
        {
        echo "<li><a href='phonereg.php?pn=$i'>$i</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        #**********************
        mysql_free_result($rs);
        }
```

Comment: Someone close the wormhole to 1999!

Comment: @keyboardSmasher Is it the answer??

Comment: i don't understand what u trying to do..

Comment: @DipeshParmar Dude i want to show database records in grid with pagination. all working fine except when i click on pagination link then grid is not visible unless i click on the button that is search button.. i want to show grid first time on button click then for second page it dose not require button click.. Hope it helps u to understand

Comment: is your page is redirecting or its done using AJAX.

Comment: @DipeshParmar no i didn't use ajax its rediresting

Comment: so problem must be there you must have code when page load so afte redirecting that code executing first so everytime page refresh you need to click button..if you don't wanna do this then you must pass something in url and need to tell browser to not apply button code just show grid when its second load...GET IT..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22431/discussion-between-bkay-and-dipesh-parmar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.hscripts.com/scripts/jquery/pagination.php

the script here is really helpful to me. Exactly what i want to do. hope anyone one in future will need this.
thanks all for suggestions.
Regards.
BKay